# How to generate gce credentials

Tags: elasticsearch, credentials

I'm trying to use a 3rd party app that requires gce_client_id and gce_client_secret keys. In order to generate them, I browsed to the Credentials icon and tried to create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID. However, the system offers me 7 different types of apps but none of them fits the app profile. The app is supposed to be run from a gce VM and spin up other gce VMs so it really has nothing to do with web apps or similar. Am I doing this right or is there any other way to generate the gce id and server keys? Thanks.

P.S. I tried using the keys generated using the option: "Desktop app" but it's producing the following error:

> ERROR Error creating instance `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/watchful-origin-244417/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`
> 2020-08-10 18:08:11 deployator0002 elasticluster[3768] ERROR Could not start node `compute002`: Error creating instance `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/watchful-origin-244417/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">` -- <class 'elasticluster.exceptions.InstanceError'>

Comment: My first question would be what’s the app?  Could you elaborate? I ask because many apps fit into one of the app types. If yours is supposed to run from a GCE VM , it should fall into one of the categories.

Comment: It's elasticluster (https://github.com/elasticluster/elasticluster). I actually generated the keys choosing 'desktop app' w/o any issue. However, I'm unsure if it was the right choice or not. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use the keys but they seem to not be working. I modified my original post to include the error output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this post has nothing to do with elasticsearch as that app is totally unrelated to elasticluster which is the app of interest (probably no need to change the original tags). The fact is that Google changed the options for OAuth 2.0 and eliminated the 'Other' option from its list of app types. That was the origin of the issue and the developer is already aware of it. Thanks.